# date validation between certain interval using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have three different text boxes(date, month,year) and need to validate the entered date(dd-mm-yyyy) between the certain interval(01/01/1900 to 31/12/2000) using jquery. if date is present between certain interval the bootstrap icon turns to success, else will be in danger. here is my code

Comment: Please post your code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have fields like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="dd" id="day" value="13">
<input type="text" placeholder="dd" id="month" value="03">
<input type="text" placeholder="yyyy" id="year" value="1995">
```

Grab them with jQuery and create a new Date Object for each of the dates:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var day = $("#day").val();
    var month = $("#month").val();
    var year = $("#year").val();
    var dateOfSomething = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
    var to = new Date(2000, 11, 31); //31/12/2000
    var from = new Date(1900, 1, 0); //01/01/1900 
    if (from < dateOfSomething && dateOfSomething < to) {
        alert("success");
    } else {
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

Here's demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dzphbb3v/